# Updating a Webquery with Visual Basic in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a webquery that after I refresh the connection, I then have to edit it to make it usable. When I made the macro to do so, it didn't record the refresh Connection part, which if it doesn't work, the number of records I have will go down everytime. Does anyone know what I could insert into the Macro with Visual Basic to get it to refresh the Webquery connection first. 
Currently, the macro looks like this

The connection's name is Standings

```
 Sub Baseball()
'
' Baseball Macro
'

'
    Range("1:3,10:10,16:16,22:24,30:30,36:36,42:46").Select
    Range("A42").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Team"
    Rows("1:1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know what I could insert into the Macro with Visual Basic to get it to refresh the Webquery connection first
>
> ...
>
> The connection's name is Standings

It looks like...

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Standings").Refresh
```

...should do it.

Comment: Thanks!!! Its good to know, although instead of using VBA, I just decided to force the connections to update at every file opening. Still, it is good to know more information. Never know when it can be useful. Thanks a bunch man.